# How to assign Bitmap to ImageControl

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to bind image to image control, but image is bitmap data. How can I?

Comment: write some code is what you need. Be more specific about whats the problem in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you have an image as binary data and you want to display it without saving it in a file? If yes, then one solution will be to create a separate aspx page or an http handler to return the image. You need to set the content type and length accordingly and use Response.BinaryWrite for serving the image.

See [here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/692253-set-image-control-bitmap) for some more suggestions.